# Make a div with two widths

Tags: html, css

I have two divs next to each other.  The div on the right is 300px x 335px.  The div on the left goes all the way down the page.  I want the width of the left div to go all the way until the right div.  Then under the right div, it takes up the whole width of the page.  Is this possible?

Comment: Uh... Just have the "right div" be `float: right` and placed before the left div in the source?

Comment: That's what I did, but the left div has the same width down the entire page, which looks dumb.

Comment: Are you asking for an "L" shaped DIV?

Comment: Probably the closest you'll get to this is to have the right DIV be inside the left DIV and have whatever's in the left DIV flow around the right DIV as a block. You can set the styles to get a variety of visual effects, so it doesn't have to look like one inside the other. But this depends on what the content of your left DIV is, which you haven't shared.

Comment: For example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qv85pdkb/)

Comment: Add a simple drawing of what you want to achieve, there seems to be too much confusion.

Answer (score 1):

div elements are [block level elements](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#block-boxes). So they are like square blocks. No, they can't work as you ask. However, you might Google for CSS Shapes to see if it can do what you wish but it's not available in all browsers and still isn't exactly the same as you request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some option either you can add min-width to the short div and long div to extend it.  or you can add a background-color body to fake the illusion of it. but like Rob said there is no good way that can work out.

```css
.short {
  width: 100px; height: 100px; 
  background:red;
  float:left;
  
  //min-height: 500px; 
}
.long {
  width: 100px; height: 500px;
  background:blue;
  float:left;
  
  //min-height: 500px;
}
.width {
  width: 100%;  
  height: 200px;
  background:yellow;
}
.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}

body {
  // background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="short"></div>
    <div class="long"></div>
</div>
<div class="width"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the method to achieve what you want
**CSS**

```css
    #left1 {
    margin-right: 300px;
    height: 335px;
    background: #aaa;
    }
    #right {
    width: 300px;
    height: 335px;
    float: right;
    }
    #left2 {
    background: #aaa;
    border: 1px soild #000;
    min-height: 300px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="left1"></div>
    <div id="left2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, although you could always put another div under the one on the right and set the margin so that it looks like it's part of the one on the left.